# routing audio through pulseaudio to a flash app running on remote machine

Tags: qemu, pulseaudio

I have multiple VMs running on qemu-kvm. I want to send audio output from each VM to its respective remote user. I want to run flash on the remote machine for this purpose.

I came across pulse audio in this regard. pulse audio can take a source and route it to a sink. I am unable to achieve this right now.

I want to understand how exactly i can take my VMs as source and send that audio to their respective remote sinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `qemu-kvm --audio-help`.

The section on pulseaudio looks something like this:

```
Name: pa
...
Options:
  ...
  QEMU_PA_SOURCE: string, default = (not set)
  QEMU_PA_SINK: string, default = (not set)
```

You should be able to set the environment variable QEMU_PA_SINK before running qemu to define the sink that the audio stream of the virtual machine should be routed to.